# How to Override existing Customer Created event in nopCommerce

Tags: events, plugins, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce version 3.5. I am trying to create a default Vendor account (attached with created customer) whenever any customer Register him/her self. I have created a Plugin that I have Installed from Admin section. I have checked in Log that Install/Uninstall & Register methods executes. But main method that I have written Is not fired at all. I tried after clearing the cache but no luck.

Following is the code I am using:

Folder Structure:
1) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Controllers (Empty)

2) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Data (Empty)

3) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Domain (Empty)

4) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Infrastructure

- Files: 1) DependencyRegistrar.cs

5) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Services

- Files: 1) CustomerService.cs

6) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module

- Files: 1) CustomerModulePlugin.cs
- Files: 2) Description.txt

**Code in Files:**

4) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Infrastructure

- Files: 1) DependencyRegistrar.cs

  ```
  namespace Nop.Plugin.Tax.CountryStateZip.Infrastructure
  {
      public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
      {
          public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
          {

               builder.RegisterType<Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module.Services.CustomerService>().As<Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService>().InstancePerRequest();

              ////we cache presentation models between requests
              //builder.RegisterType<CountryStateZipTaxProvider>()
              //    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
          }

          public int Order
          {
              get { return 1; }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

5) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module\Services
   - Files: 1) CustomerService.cs

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module.Services
{
    public class CustomerService : Nop.Services.Customers.CustomerService //Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService
    {

        #region Fields

        private readonly IRepository<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.Customer> _customerRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<CustomerRole> _customerRoleRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<GenericAttribute> _gaRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ForumPost> _forumPostRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ForumTopic> _forumTopicRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<BlogComment> _blogCommentRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<NewsComment> _newsCommentRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<PollVotingRecord> _pollVotingRecordRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ProductReview> _productReviewRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ProductReviewHelpfulness> _productReviewHelpfulnessRepository;
        private readonly IGenericAttributeService _genericAttributeService;
        private readonly IDataProvider _dataProvider;
        private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
        private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;
        private readonly CustomerSettings _customerSettings;
        private readonly CommonSettings _commonSettings;

        private readonly Nop.Services.Vendors.IVendorService _vendorService;
        private readonly Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService _customerService;

        #endregion



        public CustomerService(ICacheManager cacheManager,
            IRepository<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.Customer> customerRepository,
            IRepository<CustomerRole> customerRoleRepository,
            IRepository<GenericAttribute> gaRepository,
            IRepository<Order> orderRepository,
            IRepository<ForumPost> forumPostRepository,
            IRepository<ForumTopic> forumTopicRepository,
            IRepository<BlogComment> blogCommentRepository,
            IRepository<NewsComment> newsCommentRepository,
            IRepository<PollVotingRecord> pollVotingRecordRepository,
            IRepository<ProductReview> productReviewRepository,
            IRepository<ProductReviewHelpfulness> productReviewHelpfulnessRepository,
            IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService,
            IDataProvider dataProvider,
            IDbContext dbContext,
            IEventPublisher eventPublisher,
            CustomerSettings customerSettings,
            CommonSettings commonSettings)
            : base(
                cacheManager,
                customerRepository,
                customerRoleRepository,
                gaRepository,
                orderRepository,
                forumPostRepository,
                forumTopicRepository,
                blogCommentRepository,
                newsCommentRepository,
                pollVotingRecordRepository,
                productReviewRepository,
                productReviewHelpfulnessRepository,
                genericAttributeService,
                dataProvider,
                dbContext,
                eventPublisher,
                customerSettings,
                commonSettings
                )
        {
            this._cacheManager = cacheManager;
            this._customerRepository = customerRepository;
            this._customerRoleRepository = customerRoleRepository;
            this._gaRepository = gaRepository;
            this._orderRepository = orderRepository;
            this._forumPostRepository = forumPostRepository;
            this._forumTopicRepository = forumTopicRepository;
            this._blogCommentRepository = blogCommentRepository;
            this._newsCommentRepository = newsCommentRepository;
            this._pollVotingRecordRepository = pollVotingRecordRepository;
            this._productReviewRepository = productReviewRepository;
            this._productReviewHelpfulnessRepository = productReviewHelpfulnessRepository;
            this._genericAttributeService = genericAttributeService;
            this._dataProvider = dataProvider;
            this._dbContext = dbContext;
            this._eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
            this._customerSettings = customerSettings;
            this._commonSettings = commonSettings;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Insert a customer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customer">Customer</param>
        public override void InsertCustomer(Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.Customer customer)
        {

            if (customer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");

            _customerRepository.Insert(customer);

            //event notification
            _eventPublisher.EntityInserted(customer);

            // make registered user as a vendor too.
            {
                //Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor _vendor = new Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor();
                var vendor = new Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor()
                {
                    Name = customer.Username,
                    Email = customer.Email,
                    Active = true
                };

                this._vendorService.InsertVendor(vendor);
                customer.VendorId = vendor.Id;

                var registeredRole = _customerService.GetCustomerRoleBySystemName(SystemCustomerRoleNames.Vendors);
                if (registeredRole == null) throw new NopException("'Vendors' role could not be loaded");
                customer.CustomerRoles.Add(registeredRole);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

6) \Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module
   - Files: 1) CustomerModulePlugin.cs

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module
{
    public class CustomerModulePlugin : BasePlugin, IConsumer<EntityInserted<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.Customer>>
    {

        private readonly Nop.Services.Vendors.IVendorService _vendorService;
        private readonly Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService _customerService;

        public override void Install()
        {

            base.Install();
        }

        public void HandleEvent(EntityInserted<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.Customer> customer)
        {
            if (customer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");

            // make registered user as a vendor too.
            {
                //Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor _vendor = new Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor();
                var vendor = new Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.Vendor()
                {
                    Name = customer.Entity.Username,
                    Email = customer.Entity.Email,
                    Active = true
                };


                this._vendorService.InsertVendor(vendor);
                customer.Entity.VendorId = vendor.Id;

                var registeredRole = _customerService.GetCustomerRoleBySystemName(SystemCustomerRoleNames.Vendors);
                if (registeredRole == null) throw new Exception("'Vendors' role could not be loaded");
                customer.Entity.CustomerRoles.Add(registeredRole);
            }
        }

        public override void Uninstall()
        {
            base.Uninstall();
        }
    }
}
```

This creates following folder:

1) \Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Customer.Module

- Files: 1) Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module.dll
- Files: 2) Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module.pdb
- Files: 3) Description.txt

Then I copied the generated files in Published code of nopCommerce.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that your service is replacing the default ICustomerService? (You can check setting a breakpoint at its constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

Actually in `DependencyRegistrar.cs` file I wrongly typed following:

`namespace Nop.Plugin.Tax.CountryStateZip.Infrastructure`

Instead of:

`namespace Nop.Plugin.Customer.Module.Infrastructure`

Correcting fixed the issue.